# Tesseract running error

Tags: ocr, tesseract

I have a problem with running tesseract-ocr engine on linux. I've downloaded RUS language data and put it to tessdata directory (/usr/local/share/tessdata). When I'm trying to run tesseract with command `tesseract blob.jpg out -l rus` , it displays an error:

```
Error opening data file /usr/local/share/tessdata/eng.traineddata

Please make sure the TESSDATA_PREFIX environment variable is set to the parent directory of your "tessdata" directory.

Failed loading language eng
Tesseract couldn't load any languages!

Could not initialize tesseract.
```

According to [**compiling guide**](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/wiki/Compiling), I used `export TESSDATA_PREFIX='/usr/local/share/'`
 to point my tessdata directory.
Maybe I should edit any config files? Tesseract try to load 'eng' data files instead of 'rus'.

Screenshot:
[***https://i.stack.imgur.com/I0Guc.png***](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I0Guc.png)

Answer (score 133):

You can grab `eng.traineddata` Github:

```
wget https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata/raw/main/eng.traineddata
```

Check https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata for a full list of trained language data.

When you grab the file(s), move them to the `/usr/local/share/tessdata` folder. Warning: some Linux distributions (such as openSUSE and Ubuntu) may be expecting it in `/usr/share/tessdata` instead.

```
# If you got the data from Google, unzip it first!
gunzip eng.traineddata.gz 
# Move the data
sudo mv -v eng.traineddata /usr/local/share/tessdata/
```

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong.. but wasn't the question about including a new language (rus) and not supplying the one which the (faulty) error message points to?

Comment: edit: For some reason, tesseract won't run unless eng.traineddate is present - even if it is not needed. So AAAfarmclub's answer is fine.

Comment: Warning: other linux installations (ubuntu vivid) work in a different directory: /usr/share/tesseract-ocr/tessdata instead

Comment: @Gazta: Yes, openSUSE requires that directory instead

Comment: In Ubuntu-Gnome 16.04: it's `/usr/share/tesseract-ocr/tessdata/`

Comment: Well you can put your traineddata anywhere in your system,,just make sure you are setting path till tessdata , say you downloaded you traineddata in `/home/user/Downloads/tessdata/eng.traineddata` thenTESSDATA_PREFIX should be  `/home/user/Downloads/tessdata/`

Comment: Arch Linux: /usr/share/tessdata/
The *.traineddata can be installed by means pacman. I just haven't found the path, but now it's OK.

Comment: in ubuntu 18.04 by default is expected on
`sudo mv -v eng.traineddata /usr/local/share/tessdata/`

Comment: Thanks, it helps me a lot. Now in 2022, the correct download url is: `wget https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata/raw/main/eng.traineddata` and the directory for Ubuntu 20.04 is `sudo mv -v eng.traineddata /usr/share/tesseract-ocr/4.00/tessdata`

Comment: Ubuntu 22: sudo apt-get install libtesseract-dev tesseract-ocr-eng

Comment: If you installed tesseract through homebrew on a Mac, consider: /opt/homebrew/share/tessdata

Answer (score 104):

The simpliest way is to install the needed package:

```
sudo apt-get install tesseract-ocr-eng  #for english
sudo apt-get install tesseract-ocr-tam  #for tamil
sudo apt-get install tesseract-ocr-deu  #for deutsch (German)
```

As you can notice, it opens the road to others languages (i.e. tesseract-ocr-fra).

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Manually tinkering with files behind the package managers back (assuming you used one to install tesseract in the first place) is a bad idea

Comment: For Mac user using MacPort: sudo port install tesseract-eng

Comment: You can use `tesseract --list-langs` to see all available languages. You also can use `sudo apt-get install tesseract-ocr-*` to install all of them

Comment: for arch the packages are called `tesseract-data-eng`, etc.

Comment: unfortunately this answer doesn't work in a Docker container although it works outside of it.

Comment: Trying this command but getting an error - sudo: apt-get: command not found

Comment: These packages are the fast models, not best, for these download from https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata_best/ and put file to tesssdata dir of installation, works also in docker, e.g.: `RUN cd /usr/share/tesseract-ocr/5/tessdata && curl -O https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata_best/main/eng.traineddata` with `python:3.10-slim-bookworm`

Answer (score 45):

I had this error too on the Windows machine.

My solution.

1) Download your language files from 
https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata/tree/3.04.00

For example, for eng, I downloaded all files with eng prefix.

2) Put them into *tessdata* directory inside of some folder. Add this folder into System Path variables as *TESSDATA_PREFIX*.

Result will be
System env var: TESSDATA_PREFIX=D:/Java/OCR
And OCR folder has *tessdata* with languages files.

This is a screenshot of the directory:

[image]

Comment: Yes, everybody is talking about linux. Please guys, don't forget one more popular OS is there in market.

Answer (score 7):

For me the problem was in how I downloaded the train data files. Make sure you get the raw link.

Initially I was using:

```
wget https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata_best/blob/master/eng.traineddata
```

When I changed it to:

```
wget https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata_best/raw/master/eng.traineddata
```

It worked

Comment: That will not work. You need to change `master` by `main` in your URL.

Comment: this fixed my issues! Thanks! damn I had not realized I downloaded the JSON blob instead of the actual model....

Answer (score 5):

No previous solution worked for me.

I've installed both by `apt-get` and manually downloading the tessdata, moved around `/usr` and so on and no one worked even if i exported the variable thousand times.

Finally, on a last try before start to cry i've tried to pass the path directly to the instance of Tesseract().

In Python: `tr = Tesseract("/usr/local/share/tesseract-ocr/")` and now it works. To clarify, im using `tesserwrap` module.

Comment: I feel you! I am exactly there right now. The difference is, to make things worse, I am trying to get it working from command line.

Answer (score 5):

```
tesseract  --tessdata-dir <tessdata-folder> <image-path> stdout --oem 2 -l <lng>
```

In my case, the mistakes that I've made or attempts that wasn't a success.

- I cloned the github repo and copied files from there to

  - /usr/local/share/tessdata/
  - /usr/share/tesseract-ocr/tessdata/
  - /usr/share/tessdata/
- Used `TESSDATA_PREFIX` with above paths
- sudo apt-get install tesseract-ocr-eng

First 2 attempts did not worked because, the files from `git clone` did not worked for the reasons that I do not know. I am not sure why #3 attempt worked for me.

Finally,

1. I downloaded the eng.traindata file using `wget`
2. Copied it to some directory
3. Used `--tessdata-dir` with directory name

Take away for me is to **learn the tool well & make use of it**, rather than relying on package manager installation & directories

Answer (score 5):

For Ubuntu just run the below command and the Environment variable error will disappear.

command:

```
export TESSDATA_PREFIX=Path_of_your_tessdata_folder
```

Command Example:

```
export TESSDATA_PREFIX=/home/amar/Desktop/OCR/tesseract-4.1.1/tessdata
```

This command will set the tessdata folder's path to the environment variable with name TESSDATA_PREFIX and the above error will be resolved.

Answer (score 4):

For Windows Users:

In Environment Variables, add a new variable in system variable with name "TESSDATA_PREFIX" and value is "C:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR\tessdata"

Answer (score 3):

In Google Colab I resolved the issue in this way:

```
!sudo apt-get install tesseract-ocr-*
```

Because if you use this command `!sudo apt install tesseract-ocr` then it imports 2 languages but when you intend to work on non-English languages then the former command works.
Afterwards, use this command `!pip install pytesseract`
You can also check languages in this way `!tesseract --list-langs`

Comment: this should be the proper answer (to install the languages via the package manager and not manually download and moving the trained data to the repo, which I tried in Ubuntu 22.04 and was still getting the same message, even though the file was there with the proper permissions, and list-langs command was outputting the language I was trying to use)

Answer (score 2):

You can call tesseract API function from C code:

```
#include <tesseract/baseapi.h>
#include <tesseract/ocrclass.h>; // ETEXT_DESC

using namespace tesseract;

class TessAPI : public TessBaseAPI {
    public:
    void PrintRects(int len);
};

...
TessAPI *api = new TessAPI();
int res = api->Init(NULL, "rus");
api->SetAccuracyVSpeed(AVS_MOST_ACCURATE);
api->SetImage(data, w0, h0, bpp, stride);
api->SetRectangle(x0,y0,w0,h0);

char *text;
ETEXT_DESC monitor;
api->RecognizeForChopTest(&monitor);
text = api->GetUTF8Text();
printf("text: %s\n", text);
printf("m.count: %s\n", monitor.count);
printf("m.progress: %s\n", monitor.progress);

api->RecognizeForChopTest(&monitor);
text = api->GetUTF8Text();
printf("text: %s\n", text);
...
api->End();
```

And build this code:

```
g++ -g -I. -I/usr/local/include -o _test test.cpp -ltesseract_api -lfreeimageplus
```

(i need FreeImage for picture loading)

Comment: @DarkSkull, yes, this is C++ code tested in Debian GNU/Linux.  As you see, Russel Crowe have the problem with function TessAPI::Init(NULL, "rus").
It is meaningful to inspect the Tesseract source code (TessAPI class method).

Answer (score 2):

I'm using windows OS, I tried all solutions above and none of them work.

Finally, I install Tesseract-OCR on D drive(Where I run my python script from) instead of C drive and it works.

So, if you are using windows, run your python script in the same drive as your Tesseract-OCR.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition.

I solved this problem by making a directory called **tessdata** in the Debug directory of my project. Then I put the **eng.traineddata** file into said directory.

Answer (score 1):

C# developer working on Windows here. What works for me is simply download the file *eng.traineddata* from the following URL:

https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata/blob/master/eng.traineddata

and copy it to the following directory in my Console Application project:

[Project Directory]\bin\Debug\tessdata

I did manually create the *tessdata* folder above.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with DEU language on macOS. I could solve it by installing all additional languages like so:

```
brew install tesseract-lang
```

as suggested on https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/tesseract

Answer (score 0):

```
tessdata_dir_config = r'--tessdata-dir "/usr/local/Cellar/tesseract/4.1.1/share/tessdata"'
pytesseract.image_to_string(imgCrop,lang='eng',config=tessdata_dir_config)
```

Comment: This isn't an answer. Please explain what is going on here so others can gain useful insights when reading your response.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your code :

```
instance.setDatapath("C:\\somepath\\tessdata");

instance.setLanguage("eng");
```

Answer (score 0):

How I solved the problem in my Manjaro Xfce:

Message “TesseractError: (1, 'Error opening data file /home/julio/snap/tesseract/common/eng.traineddata Please make sure the TESSDATA_PREFIX environment variable is set to your "tessdata" directory. Failed loading language 'eng' Tesseract couldn't load any languages! Could not initialize tesseract.')”

Then, in my Manjaro, I typed: sudo pacman -S tesseract
Then the system installed both the “tesseract” and also a package name “leptonica”

After this step, I thought everything was ok, and tried to run my simple script. However, the error message changed to something like this (it changed the previous “/home” location to other “/usr”-like location):
“"Please make sure the TESSDATA_PREFIX environment variable is set to your "tessdata" directory. Failed loading language 'eng' Tesseract couldn't load any languages! Could not initialize tesseract.')"”

Then I realized that there had appeared this message when I installed “tesseract” with pacman: “You must install one of tesseract-data-* packages or whole tesseract-data group”

So, I tried the command: “sudo pacman -S tesseract-data”, and the system presented lots of language options to me. So I’ve chosen some languages, installed as follows, and the module started to work like a charm:

sudo pacman -S tesseract-data-eng

sudo pacman -S tesseract-data-por

sudo pacman -S tesseract-data-fra

sudo pacman -S tesseract-data-spa

I tried some portuguese special characters (like "ão"), that only worked when I used the argument "lang='por'" in the pytesseract.image_to_string(img,lang='por')

Answer (score 0):

As of 2021, My solution for Ubuntu is to download the zip files from `https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata_best/releases/tag/4.1.0`, extract and copy the neccessary `.traineddata` files into `/usr/local/share/tessdata`. This is the default folder for tesseract 4.1.1 to search for trained data.

Comment: @innovationism By default the files are present here `/usr/share/tesseract-ocr/4.00/tessdata/` on Ubuntu 20.04. Tesseract is version 4.1.1. And on placing tessdata_best files here tesseract throws an error. How did you resolve this issue, in case you faced it?

Answer (score 0):

**IF you have windows OS then please add your TesseractOCR to system variable.
Eg..

1. Find the path where Tesseract is installed in your c drive (in my case r"C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe")**
   2)make sure you have the required files ie tessdata, tessdata if not then download it from  https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata  https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/langdata (At least those languages which you want to convert)
2. past it into the main directory in my case C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR
   4)Add the path of the directory to your system environment variable
   for that
   search environment variable in start bar
   go to environment variable
   click path in your system environment variable (NOT IN USER ENVIRONMENT VARIABLE)
   past the path of tesseractocr

thats all...

Answer (score 0):

For windows , all you need to do is

1. download the language you want
2. store that in any folder preferably in tessdata
3. set the **system** (not user) environment variable in advanced system settings (eg:
   `C:\Userseclipse-workspace\tessdata`)
   variable name : `TESSDATA_PREFIX`
   variable value: (eg:`C:\Userseclipse-workspace\tessdata`)
4. restart the your laptop

Answer (score 0):

On macOS, installed via macports:

After installing tesseract run
`sudo port install tesseract-osd` to enable the 'osd'.  This solved the error for me.

Answer (score 0):

Just adding some options to the list -- on RHEL and related systems, `sudo dnf [or yum] install tesseract` installs `tesseract-langpack-eng` by default. It looks like others may have to be downloaded manually.