# Tesseract is not initializing

Tags: ios, xamarin, tesseract

I'm using Visual Studio and want to use Xamarin (from Artur Shamsutdinov in Version 0.3.4) for native iOS

I get the following error:

> Please make sure the TESSDATA_PREFIX environment variable is set to
>   the parent directory of your "tessdata" directory. Failed loading
>   language 'deu' Tesseract couldn't load any languages!

The "tessdata" folder is located in my Solution under "Resources":

[image]

And I added the environment variable TESSDATA_PREFIX in the project properties to the (parent) directory of tessdata, which is Resources

[image]

What did I do wrong? Could somebody help me, please?

Kindest regards

Comment: Have you checked this? https://github.com/gali8/Tesseract-OCR-iOS/issues/355

Comment: This may solve your issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14800730/tesseract-running-error

Comment: Download eng.traineddata file from this url https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata/raw/master/eng.traineddata and paste it in /usr/local/share/tessdata folder