# Failure to load languages in Tesseract 4.0

Tags: ocr, tesseract, image-recognition

I'm having an issue trying to run tesseract-ocr on my macbook pro (Sierra). I know this question has be asked before: [Tesseract running error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14800730/tesseract-running-error),
However, none of the listed answers are providing me with any solution.

This is the output I am getting from terminal:

`Please make sure the TESSDATA_PREFIX environment variable is set to the parent directory of your "tessdata" directory.
Failed loading language 'eng'
Tesseract couldn't load any languages!
Could not initialize tesseract.`

Does anyone know of an alternative solution to this issue?

Comment: Ran into this problem today on Mac OS Mojave and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49030935/9987623) in the thread linked above, particularly the comment about replacing a bad 4MB eng.traineddata file with a new one from Github, solved the issue.